# Removing edges from a 2d array

Tags: java, arrays, copy, 2d, edge-detection

I have an array [300][300] and I need to get rid of the edges and populate a new array [298][298] with the remaining values.  I've got this far so far:

```
double[][] edging() {
   double [][] array = new double [data.length] [data[0].length];
   array = bubbles();   
   double [] [] newArray = new double[array.length-2][array[0].length-2]; 

   System.arraycopy(array,1,newArray, 0, newArray.length);

   array = newArray;
   System.out.println( + newArray.length);  
   System.out.println( + newArray[0].length);   

   return newArray;
}
```

This works to remove the top and bottom edges.  However, the right and left are still there. The checks in there show me that the new array is [298][300].

I've thought about writing a loop to remove each row in turn, use arraycopy on each one and return the new row.  Not sure if this would be very efficient though.

Tried this but to no avail. Next one up for a test is rotating it and using the above code again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go. You do not necessarily want to use the System.arraycopy() since it still performs in O(n^2) running time. In the below program, I have not handled the edge cases, but this should do it for you.

```
class MyClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyClass myClass = new MyClass();

        int[][] sampleArray = {{11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16},
                {17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22},
                {23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28},
                {29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34},
        };

        myClass.removeEdges(sampleArray);
    }


    public int[][] removeEdges(int[][] arrayToTrim){
        int[][] newArray = new int[arrayToTrim.length-2][arrayToTrim[0].length-2];
        print2DArray(arrayToTrim);
        for(int i=1;i<arrayToTrim.length-1;i++){
            for(int j=1;j<arrayToTrim[0].length-1;j++){
                newArray[i-1][j-1] = arrayToTrim[i][j];
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
        print2DArray(newArray);
        return newArray;
    }

    private void print2DArray(int[][] anArray){
        for(int i=0;i<anArray.length;i++){
            System.out.println();
            for(int j=0;j<anArray[0].length;j++){
                System.out.print(anArray[i][j]+" ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The output of the above program is

```
11 12 13 14 15 16 
17 18 19 20 21 22 
23 24 25 26 27 28 
29 30 31 32 33 34 

18 19 20 21 
24 25 26 27
```

Comment: Thanks Bragboy.  I'll definitely give this a try.   Much more elegant than what I just came up with. I used the arraycopy to remove the top and bottom edge, rotated it 90 degrees, repeated the arraycopy and then rotated it back.  Clunky and horrible and I'm surprised ti even worked.

Comment: @Oliver Burdekin : Although it worked, Arraycopy is a costly method in terms of running time. Please try to avoid it as much as possible.

Comment: Yep just tested and confirmed.  You're a genius.  Thank you again Bragboy!